# Is there a way that I can get the SNR (Signal-To-Noise Ratio) using CaptiveNetwork?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa

Is there a way that I can get the SNR (Signal-To-Noise Ratio) of a wifi AP using CaptiveNetwork?  If there isn't, is the Wifi device on the iPhone capable of doing so?  Also, I can't seem to get the signal strength of any wifi AP using CaptiveNetwork.  It only gives me SSID, BSSID and SSIDDATA.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is 'No' if using CaptiveNetwork. 
However, if you do not plan to submit your app to Appstore, you could use the private API - [Apple80211](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/) on a jailbroken device.

You'll be able to obtain a bunch of info like RSSI, Rate, Channel etc as shown [Here](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211GetInfoCopy)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried using Apple80211Scan because I need to get the noise but it seems that it always have a zero value.  I even tried the WifiTrak app (on a jailbroken phone) and the noise value also returns zero.  Am I missing something?